# How to rollback a transactional database operation and save the error message into another table?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I'm using Spring and Hibernate trying to update a value of the database. It is needed that, in case of exceptions, save the error message into a table.  I'm facing some errors because when I'm able to save the message into the database, the transaction doesn't rollback. Here is the pseudo-code

```
@Transactional
public class ObjectTable(){
    //instanciate other objects
    RelatedObject relatedObject = relatedObjectController.getObjectById(primaryKey)
    Object object =  objectController.getObjectByRelatedObject(relatedObject.getPrimaryKey())



    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public updateObject(Object object) throws MyCustomException{
         try{
             getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(object);
             getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
             getSession.flush();
         }catch(Exception ex){
              saveErrorMessageIntoDatabase(ex.getMessage, this.relatedObject);
              throw new MyCustomException(ex.getMessage)
         }
    }

    public saveErrorMessageIntoDatabase(String message, RelatedObject relatedObject){
         relatedObject.setErrorMessage(message);
         getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(relatedObject);
         getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(relatedObject);
         getSession.flush();
    }

}
```

With this kind of tought, I'm not being able to save the message in `relatedObject` and rollback the changes in `object`. Making a few variations, such as putting a `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` or `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED` or removing the Excpection.class for rollback, I get some other behaviours, like save the error message but also writes the changes of `object` when there is an exception, or rollin back the changes but also not writing the error message into `relatedObject`.

I also tried with `merge` instead of `saveOrUpdate`, but with no success.

Could someone help me write a way to rollback changes in case of error but also save the error message into the database?

Thank you.

*I don't post the actual code because this is not a personal project.

EDIT:
My `transactionManager` is configured as a XML bean where first I create the `objectTableTarget` setting the `sessionFactory` property and bellow that I set another bean `objectTable` refering to the methods I want to set as transactional.

```
<bean id="objectTableTarget" class="br.com.classes.ObjectTable" singleton="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="objectTable" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="target" ref="objectTableTarget" />

    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="updateObject*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-br.com.package.exception.MyCustomException</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

move your log method into separate service and annotate it with
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

```
    @Service
    public class ErrorLoggerService(){
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public saveErrorMessageIntoDatabase(String message, RelatedObject relatedObject){
             relatedObject.setErrorMessage(message);
             getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(relatedObject);
             getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(relatedObject);
             getSession.flush();
        }
}
```

Then spring can create proxy on your method and error should be write in new transaction

Comment: first of all, thank you very much for your answer. Indeed the error is setted in the database, but I'm facing the same problem I mentioned, that the `object` update method is being saved into the database. The rollback is not happening :(

Comment: I posted in a etit session how I configure it. The error log method since I putted in another file it follows the same configuration, just changed the name of the file and the method.